# how to create a new text file and store an encrypted string?

Tags: encryption, fileinputstream

i want to create a new file and store the encrypted string into that file. how can i create a new text file and store this in that file using java.i found some java codes online which are not clear to me.

encrypted = cipher.doFinal(strContent.toString().getBytes());

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: search in stackoverflow and google before asking questions

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the file in java by writing the following line:

File file=new File("C:/users/new.txt"); /**You can give the address where you want to create the file with file name as here it is "new.txt"**/

For wiriting the file you can make the object of BufferedWriter with parameter of FileWriter(file name).EX-

BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

now use **bw.write(String)** to write string in the file.
Note:-Don't forget to close the BufferedWriter object simply by typing **bw.close()**.